# JAVA and generic types issue

Tags: java, generics

I'm facing an issue with generic types:

```
public static class Field<T> {

    private Class<? extends T> clazz;

    public Field(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1. (warning) Iterable is a raw type. References to generic type Iterable<T> should be parameterized.
    new Field<Iterable>(List.class);

    // 2. (error) The constructor Main.Field<Iterable<?>>(Class<List>) is undefined.
    new Field<Iterable<?>>(List.class);

    // 3. (error) *Simply unpossible*
    new Field<Iterable<?>>(List<?>.class);

    // 4. (warning) Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<List> to Class<? extends Iterable<?>>.
    new Field<Iterable<?>>((Class<? extends Iterable<?>>) List.class);

}
```

What's the best solution between the 1. and the 4. (or any other one by the way)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's hard to answer your question without knowing that...

Comment: Class can be a nasty beast. 5th option: `new Field<Iterable<Object>>(List.class)` ('warning: unchecked assignment').

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class object of generic class (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java)

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup It's an example that reflects an issue I'm facing with the custom objects of the project I'm working on. So I'm afraid I can't be more specific, sorry...

Comment: @akaIDIOT With your solution, I'm not getting a warning but an error: *The constructor Main.Field<Iterable<Object>>(Class<List>) is undefined*.

Comment: @sp00m curious, copied the warning from my IDE running Java 1.7...

Comment: @akaIDIOT I'm using 1.6, maybe 1.7 is more compliant with those generic types?

Comment: @sp00m could be, don't have Java 1.6 handy; can't check...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Field <T> {
    private Class <? extends T> clazz;

    public <TT extends T> Field (Class <TT> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Field <Iterable <?>> (List.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen type parameters on a constructor before, but nice solution

Comment: This is really awesome, I had never noticed that you could infer generic types to constructors. That said, I don't really understand why this solution doesn't cause the same error as in 2...

Comment: @sp00m Pretty sure it abuses a compiler bug ( see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11570215/774444 ).